# Turn M x (n*N) into (n*M) x N dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, reshape

I have a dataframe `df1` with `M` rows and `n*N` columns. The columns are named

`1.1,...,1.N,2.1,...,2.N,...n.1,...n.N`

The rows are indexed `1,...M`.

What is an elegant way to turn this into a new dataframe `df2` with n*M rows indexed `1.1,...,1.M,...,n.1,...n.M` and `N` columns named `1,...,N`, such that

`df2.iloc[i*M+j,:]==df1.iloc[j,i*n:(i+1)*N]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and last flatten `MultiIndex` by `f-string`s:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.split('.', expand=True)
df = df.stack(0)
df.index = [f'{a}.{b}' for a, b in df.index]
```

Comment: `df.columns.str.split('.', expand=True)` - amazing. Luckily the format of my column names actually has this format. (Well, I guess otherwise I could first name them like that, then use your solution, and then rename everything)